# Fit formula into column

Tags: math-mode, margins, two-column

I work in a 2-columned page and have the following code:

```
Where:
\[
b_{d,j}(w_{n},w_{m}) = \begin{cases}
    1,& w_{n},w_{m} \in \{w_{d,j}^{C}, w_{d,j+1}^{C}, ... , w_{d,j+s}^{C} \}, \\
    0,& else. \\
\end{cases}, w_{n},w_{m} \in W_{k}
\]
```

Which shows as:

[image]

Hence, it is larger than the column margins. What can I do to make it fit?

Comment: Smaller fonts? break first line in two? for series in the first define new variable? You should provide MWE that we can see your page layout and used fonts.

Comment: Please elaborate, why you after case havemath term? can it be in new line below case?

Comment: Please provide the `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this isn't really a TeX question (at least as it is currently posed), it's more of a typographical question, "how do I make text fit into a column where it doesn't?" This isn't an issue specific to TeX after all. In general there isn't one best/good way to do this. A lot of it comes down to rethinking how you're writing/formatting your document.

Comment: Where does `w_{n},w_{m} \in W_{k}` belong to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two posibilitiea as mentioned in my comments:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
With smaller font as defined by use of the \verb+\medmath+ of \verb+nccmath+ package:
\[\medmath{
b_{d,j}(w_{n},w_{m}) = 
\begin{cases}
    1,& w_{n},w_{m} \in \{w_{d,j}^{C}, w_{d,j+1}^{C},\dotsc, w_{d,j+s}^{C} \}, \\
    0,& \text{else}. \\
\end{cases}}
\]
or with normal font size and new variable for series $\{w_{d,j}^{C}, w_{d,j+1}^{C},\dotsc, w_{d,j+s}^{C}\}$:
\[
b_{d,j}(w_{n},w_{m}) = 
\begin{cases}
    1,& w_{n},w_{m} \in W_k \\
    0,& \text{else}. \\
\end{cases},
\]
where 
\[
W_{k} = \{w_{d,j}^{C}, w_{d,j+1}^{C}, ... , w_{d,j+s}^{C} \}
\]
or what your equation should be?

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]